# How to update multiple records value in database using laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Initially, `students` table looks like below.

```
id | invite_count
-----------------
10 | 5
12 | 0
15 | 1
25 | 0
```

I am using the below code to update the invite count for students.

```
Student::whereIn("id", $this->request->studentIds)
        ->update([
            'invite_count' => DB::raw('invite_count+1')
        ]);
```

But according to my requirement, I can have the same id more than one time in the `$this->request->studentIds` array like [10, 15, 12, 10, 25, 12].

At the movement, the output looks like below.

```
id | invite_count
-----------------
10 | 6
12 | 1
15 | 2
25 | 1
```

But I want output like below.

```
id | invite_count
-----------------
10 | 7
12 | 2
15 | 2
25 | 1
```

How can I archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using chunk query using [chunkById](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results).To work update make sure to  `invite_count` column fillable in model

```
$ids=[10, 15, 12, 10, 25, 12];

$groupByIds=array_count_values($ids);


Student::whereIn("id",array_keys($groupByIds))
        ->chunkById(50, function ($students)use($groupByIds) {
            $students->each(function ($student, $key)use($groupByIds) {
                $student->update(['invite_count' => $student->invite_count+($groupByIds[ $student->id])]);
            });

        }, $column = 'id');
```

or

```
 Student::whereIn("id",array_keys($groupByIds))
            ->chunkById(50, function ($students)use($groupByIds) {
                $students->each(function ($student, $key)use($groupByIds) {
                    $student->invite_count=$student->invite_count+$groupByIds[ $student->id]);
$student->save();
                });

        }, $column = 'id');
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Thanks @John for your answer. But here you are using each loop with an update then I think it will do update separately for each?

Comment: @Senthur yes separate loop but with query chunk so it won't retrieve all records once . If it's possible without a loop then it's good but not sure in your use case it can be done since increment is purely based on a number of ids count so. Let's wait if someone comes with a better solution so we both learn from it

Comment: Thanks I upvoted your answer. It's actually a good solution. But I will wait as you mentioned answer let's see.

Comment: above code isn't updating the value in the db.

Comment: we want to use `save` instead of `update`. So we want to edit the above answer.

Comment: @Senthur  update also works but it must be $fillable property in model .I mean invite_count is fillable property in model or we can use save method

Comment: you are correct. the `update` also works if we add in the `fillable`. Anyway, both will work. Thanks again. I don't think any better answer will come. so I approved.